# Redirect a single page from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: php, .htaccess, http, redirect, https

I have a site that fully runs on HTTPS. And there is a file that does not need to be loaded in HTTPS. Therefore I tried to redirect it from htaccess but it didnt work.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^xml$ http://mysite/api.php [L,R=301]
```

Here are the lines I tried but they did not work.

I tried this also but negative.
[HTTPS to HTTP htaccess redirect for home page only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156574/https-to-http-htaccess-redirect-for-home-page-only)

Comment: What URL you don't want to be on HTTPS?

Comment: @anubhava https:// mysite/xml to http:// mysite/xml while all the other pages work as https:// mysite/*

Comment: But then why do you have `/api.php` in target? Can you show your full .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

you could just use a simple 301 redirect. Just put this in your .htaccess

```
redirect 301 /api.php http://mysite/api.php
```

That should work becuase it's just taking the api.php file on either https or http and telling it to go to