# https to http redirect for two pages

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, http, redirect, ssl

My site (WordPress, in case it’s important) has ssl enabled with the following ‘rewrite’ rule in the htaccess file …

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

I have two pages I would ‘disable’ ssl for …

```
https://www.example.com/firstpage.php
https://www.example.com/someotherpage.php
```

The problem I have is that each of these pages has a highcharts chart on. For some reason, the highcharts rendering server that is used for exports doesn’t like the fact ssl is enabled on a page. This results in, horrible ‘this is insecure’ messages, and missing images when exporting a chart. Highcharts suggest [here](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/setting-up-the-server) that a way to avoiding these issues is to, basically, build your own rendering engine … but I think this might be overkill.

So may I ask how I would remove ssl for the pages mentioned above. I know you like to see something I have tried but I have two problems.

1. I think I may well, make some catastrophic mistake with this file and    cause some real damage.
2. I really don’t know where to start, as I seem    to be understanding    very little of what I read here on SO. For    example, I did try the    following based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26972983/redirect-a-single-page-from-https-to-http).

   ```
   redirect 301 /firstpage.php http://example.com/firstpage/
   ```

May I ask SO for some pointers / help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding conditions to your existing rule so that those 2 pages don't get redirected to SSL:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
# RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/firstpage\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/someotherpage\.php
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I appreciate you taking time to answer. I'll do just that and report back.

Comment: thanks. That's it. Will accept you answer in 30 secs ... (SO won't allow me to right now).